# Troubleshooting Ubuntu Server 17.04 Issues

Tags: server

I have Ubuntu 17.04 Server installed on a box that is running the following hardware:

- CPU: Ryzen 5 1600
- Motherboard: ASUS Prime A320M-K
- RAM: 8 GB DDR4 2133
- 120 GB SSD
- 4 TB HDD
- 550 W PSU
- LG WH16NS40 Blu-Ray drive

I use it to primarily run the following:

- PLEX Media Server
- ssh
- Occasionally to rip BluRays and DVDs using MakeMKV

The problem I'm having is from time to time the system becomes completely unresponsive. Can't ping it, can't ssh in, plex goes offline. The only way I can get it to come back up is to restart it using the restart button on the case.

Most of the troubleshooting I've done has been hardware related:

I don't believe that it is a power issue because I have a NAS system on the same power circuit and it has remained up and stable for weeks while I have had to manually restart this system several times a week lately. The PSU is pretty overkill for the needs of the system, as far as I can tell. I just ordered a Kill A Watt Electricity Usage Monitor to verify, but so far it seems less a power issue than a system stability issue.

I have run Memtest86+ to make sure it's not memory.

**So now, what can I do to use Ubuntu to try and figure out what is going on?**

I've started troubleshooting on the software side by looking over logs like /var/log/systemlog and /var/log/kern.log and I see now obvious issues. Logs just kind of end around the time the system stops being responsive without any obvious problems. Are there any other logs that I might be able to look at? Is there a good way to figure out what exactly went wrong? I'm pretty new to troubleshooting something like this and would love some advice.

Output of free -h:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.8G        808M        6.4G        9.4M        610M        6.7G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
```

Output of swapon -s:

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition       8318972 0       -1
```

Stuff from /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/plexbox--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=DE7B-3E50  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/plexbox--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=13af9aaa-871d-496e-9775-875cf4303e04       /mnt/media      ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show me the `terminal` output of `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `cat /etc/fstab` and I'll take a look. Start comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema added requested details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reviewed your `terminal` output of `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `cat /etc/fstab`, and didn't find the encrypted swapfile that I was expecting to see, so your problem isn't there.

I do see a *possible* problem in your `/etc/fstab`. Edit this file with:

In `terminal`...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

**Change this:**

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=DE7B-3E50  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

**To this:**

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
# UUID=DE7B-3E50  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
UUID=DE7B-3E50  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

(duplicate the 2nd line, comment out the 2nd line, and make the edit to the new 3rd line... this way you can easily go back if you need/want to).

Reboot the server and monitor for freezes.

**Troubleshooting tip:**

After rebooting the server, log into the server and type `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and keep that output in the foreground. It'll show you the current/last entries made into syslog, and may give some clue as to where the problem is when the system freezes (if it still does).

Comment: Well, it's been four days and there hasn't been a problem! So it seems to have done the trick. Thank you!What exactly was going on?

Comment: @JMorg glad it seems to have solved your problem. I've used that fix a few times... but I don't know exactly how that line got that way... it seems the installer does that... but I don't know how to explain how the fix works... but it does.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say thanks and add that this worked for me as well.  I have the operating system on on older SSD drive which had worked for a while then it started freezing.  After the fstab change it's been solid for weeks